# What genuine references are there in Voltaire’s "U.S.S. Make Shit Up" song?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos

Since Voltaire claims the quotes were mostly based on fan input and his own recollection of the series, I was wondering if it would be possible to get all the episodes together that contain the scenes that the song is based on.

This is the version from the album BiTrektual:

> Well, I was stranded on a planet, just me and Spock
>   We met a nasty Nazi alien, he locked our asses up
>   We found a hunk of crystal and a metal piece of bed
>   We made a laser phaser gun and shot him in the head!

I think I remember a episode where Kirk and Spock build a phaser gun from scraps, but I have no clue which episode it could be.

> Well, I was standing on the bridge when Sulu came to me
>   His eyes were full of tears, he said, "Captain, can't you see?
>   The ship is gonna blow, do something, I beseech!"
>   I grabbed a tribble and some chewing gum and stopped the warp core breach

Absolutely, no or?

> And I said, Bounce a graviton particle beam off the main deflector dish
>   That's the way we do things...

Any idea anyone?

> And if you're at a party on the starship Enterprise
>   And the karaoke player just plain old up and dies
>   Set up a neutrino field inside a can of peas
>   Hold on to Geordi's visor and sing into Data's knees

No, for sure I have never seen this! I would remember that! Is any of that based on any "real" Star Trek stuff?

> Sisko's on a mission to go no bloody place
>   He loiters on a space station above Bajoran space
>   The wormhole opened up and now they come from near and far
>   We'll keep the booze but please send back the f—ing Jem’Hadar

That’s DS9 ok, but is there anything else to grab in there?

> And what is with the Klingons? Remember, in the day
>   They looked like Puerto Ricans and they dressed in gold lamé
>   Now they look like heavy metal rockers from the dead
>   With leather pants and frizzy hair and lobsters on their heads

Ok, I get that.

> Well, I was stuck on Voyager, pounding on the door
>   When suddenly it dawned on me I've seen this show before
>   Perhaps I'm in a warp bubble slightly out of phase
>   'Cause it was way back in the sixties when they called it "Lost in Space"

Loved that series as well!

> We were looking for a way to make the ratings soar
>   So we orchestrated an encounter with the Borg
>   Normally you'd think that that would get us into shit
>   But this one has a smashing ass and a lovely set of tits

Ok, that is Season 4 Voyager when 7 of 9 gets introduced.

> Well then they got a new show and it's called Enterprise
>   And it takes place a hundred years before Kirk was alive
>   They say that it's a prequel or so that's what it's called
>   It's such a bad idea you'd swear that Lucas was involved

Lucas? What did I miss? George Lucas?

> They have a Vulcan female but she's a nervous wreck
>   Her ass is sweet as Seven's only green so what the heck
>   They're in the past but Klingons have those lobsters on their heads
>   I'm more confused than Wesley Crusher nude in Tasha's bed

Wesley Crusher nude in Tasha's bed??? Ok, I must have missed or suppressed that completely!

> Well it would seem a big wig up at Paramount
>   Must have felt the franchise was stale by all accounts
>   Cause he hired J. J. Abrams to give the thing a shove
>   I feared that he would mock and mangle everything I love
>   Well I went to the movie and there much to my shock
>   There were hunky models playing Kirk and Spock
>   Vulcan's been destroyed and the timeline has been crushed
>   So someone tell me why I love this film so fucking much

Ok, this one is easy, there are not that many movies...

> What does God need with a starship?

?

Thanks for helping out! [The song is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwhAq3F8NCE) if that helps...

Comment: Aside:  Apparently [this Voltaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire_(musician)), not [_the_ Voltaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaire)

Comment: @Izkata I almost googled "Is Voltaire really alive?"

Comment: Plus-oned for introducing me to this song.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**"What does God need with a starship?"** is from [Star Trek V: The Final Frontier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYW_lPlekiQ)

**"They have a Vulcan female But she's a nervous wreck"** - Likely a reference to T'Pol who suffered mental illness as a result of [exposure to trellium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T'Pol#Overview)

**"Klingons have those lobsters on their heads I'm more confused than Wesley Crusher nude in Tasha's bed"** - Wesley never slept with Tasha. I think this is a reference to the fact that Trek : Enterprise Klingons had ridged foreheads whereas [those in TOS did not](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon_augment_virus)

**"It's such a bad idea you'd swear that Lucas was involved"** - This one is a bit harsh, but Enterprise is the only recent Trek show to be prematurely cancelled. “Lucas” is indeed George Lucas, who made [prequels to his Star Wars trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars#Prequel_trilogy) [which were widely derided](http://www.slashfilm.com/watch-this-70-minute-video-review-of-star-wars-the-phantom-menace/).

**"Perhaps I'm in a warp bubble slightly out of phase"** - I think they've gotten confused with TNG: Remember Me where Dr Crusher gets stuck in a [Static Warp Bubble](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Remember_Me_(episode))

**"The wormhole opened up and now they come from near and far, We'll keep the booze"** - This is a reference to DS9: [Rules of Acquisition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) where the Ferengi attempt to buy wine from the Dosi, a client species of the Dominion.

**"Bounce a graviton particle beam off the main deflector dish"** - This happened several times in both Voyager (to open a path to fluidic space) and TNG (as a [weapon against the borg](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Graviton_beam))

**"Just me and Spock We met a nasty Nazi alien / We made a laser phaser gun "** - A reference to TOS : Patterns of Force, an episode where the Enterprise crew encounter [nazi space aliens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patterns_of_Force_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series))

Comment: The fourth season of Enterprise explains in-universe the "we do not speak of it" dissonance between Klingon foreheads  with and without "lobsters".

Comment: can it be that Patterns of Force never aired in Germany? For sure I do not remember seeing is as a kid. Thanks for answering that quickly, my daugther was planing to do a fan video and wanted to see if I could find the matching footage for her, some of your input makes it already a lot easier! If you want to I put you in the credits...

Comment: @fgwaller - It has aired in Germany; http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Patterns_of_Force_(episode)#Controversy

Comment: I had to recheck, but "Patterns of Force" was one of the episodes that did not air in Germany during the original release and not during the many reruns, it was only in 2011 that this episode was widely aired. Before then it was only available in a few late-night specials on regional stations.

Comment: Re: "More confused than Wesley nude in Tasha's bed": I assume it's because he would have no idea how he got there or what to do; i.e. very confused.

Comment: Widely derided prequels, that's true...but there are also those pesky "improvements" to Episodes IV-VI.

Comment: @Praxis - [Don't get me started](http://www.starwars7news.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tupac-hologram-with-star-wars-holograms11.jpg)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the whole "Perhaps I'm in a warp bubble slightly out of phase" thing is just trek-style technobabble to say that maybe he's slipped into an alternate universe where the Voyager premise is original instead of being a rip-off of Lost in Space.

Comment: @Iker - Given that they're referenced specific episodes elsewhere in the song, it seems far more likely that they're also referring to an episode rather than spouting *generic* treknobabble.

Answer (score 2):

The party on the Starship Enterprise sounds a lot like the TNG episode "The Next Phase" where Ro and Geordi are presumed dead but are really just out of phase with the rest of the crew (and therefore invisible to them) after mucking around with some cloaking technology. The Enterprise crew decides to throw a party-style funeral for their "fallen" shipmates. However, Geordi and Ro attend the party while still invisible, and they find a way to make their presence known by creating an energy field that Data eventually notices. When they come back to reality, they're huddled on the ground together, Ro grabbing hold of Geordi, and Data standing over them.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Answer (score -2):

> We found a hunk of crystal and a metal piece of bed
>   We made a laser phaser gun and shot him in the head!

This is actually a direct reference to the episode "The City on the Edge of Forever" from *Star Trek: The Original Series*.

Comment: For those of us who haven't seen it (yeah, shoot me), I would suggest to [edit] your post to say how it matches :) (can be a brief summary of the episode, a clip, etc)

Comment: ....I have no idea how this relates to City on the Edge of Forever @Jenayah - maaaaybe the hunk of crystal is The Guardian of Forever?

Comment: @NKCampbell not having seen the episode (...nor much of ST stuff for that matter) it looked like a possible answer, but as you're obviously more knowledgeable than I am in this matter, I'll refer to your judgment about it being a NAA or not :)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, the scene in question is from Patterns of Force as stated in the original answer.  "The transponders have rubidnium crystals inside, which can be used to excite light and create a laser.* Spock uses Kirk’s back as a table to get to the incandescent bulb in their cell, and after a few moments the light is transformed by the crystal into a metal-cutting laser that breaks the lock on their door." from https://www.tor.com/2010/06/04/lemgstar-treklemg-re-watch-patterns-of-force/